# Creating dataframe on proto case class with bcl.DateTime field throws none is not a term exception

Tags: apache-spark, scalapb

I have a case class generated from a .proto file through scalapb, which has a few fields with bcl.DateTime type. The case class definition is as follows:

```
@SerialVersionUID(0L)
final case class EditorialAdEntity(
    customerid: _root_.scala.Int = 0,
    accountid: _root_.scala.Int = 0,
    orderId: _root_.scala.Long = 0L,
    entityId: _root_.scala.Long = 0L,
    dataFeedId: _root_.scala.Long = 0L,
    editorialStatusModifiedDTim: _root_.scala.Option[bcl.bcl.DateTime] = _root_.scala.None,
    modifiedDTim: _root_.scala.Option[bcl.bcl.DateTime] = _root_.scala.None,
    adTitle: _root_.scala.Predef.String = "",
    adDescription: _root_.scala.Predef.String = "",
    adDescription2: _root_.scala.Predef.String = "",
    displayURL: _root_.scala.Predef.String = "",
    businessName: _root_.scala.Predef.String = "",
...
```

I am able to create an instance of this case class and view the contents as follows:

```
val currentDt: DateTime = DateTime.of(value = Some(DateTimeUtils.getCurrentMillis), kind = Some(DateTimeKind.UTC), scale = Some(TimeSpanScale.MILLISECONDS))
val entity: EditorialAdEntity = EditorialAdEntity(customerid = customerId, accountid = accountId, adTitle = "test",
          orderId = orderId, serviceLevelId = 5, campaignType = campaignType,
          createdDtim = Some(currentDt), modifiedDTim = Some(currentDt),
          editorialStatusModifiedDTim = Some(currentDt) )
        
Logger.logInfo(entity.toProtoString)
```

However, when I create a Spark dataframe on top of this, as follows:

```
val data = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(entity))
data.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a term
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asTerm(Symbols.scala:199)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asTerm(Symbols.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.constructParams(ScalaReflection.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.constructParams(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.getConstructorParameters(ScalaReflection.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.getConstructorParameters(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:724)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:724)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:784)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:724)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:724)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:784)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:724)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:720)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:285)
    at Scripts.SampleScripts.Protobuf.demo.EnforcementProtoTester$.main(EnforcementProtoTester.scala:43)
    at Scripts.SampleScripts.Protobuf.demo.EnforcementProtoTester.main(EnforcementProtoTester.scala)
```

If I remove the DateTime fields from the proto class it seems to work fine. Any pointers on how to create dataframes on top of proto classes withbcl.DateTime fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use ScalaPB generated class with Spark, you need to add a library dependency on `sparksql-scalapb`, and use `ProtoSQL.createDataFrame()` instead of `spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame`. The process is described here: https://scalapb.github.io/sparksql.html#using-sparksql-scalapb